# The Duality of Electricity and Magnetism

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, duality-theorems

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}$In pure mathematics, the idea of duality pops up all over the place, and most generally (as far as I know) it can be defined in category theory in terms of the opposite category $C^{op}$. In each of these cases, there is usually a satisfying conceptual explanation behind the duality, and these often are very important in the theory. For example:

- Vector spaces $V$ over a field $K$ have a dual space $V^*=\Hom(V,K)$. For finite dimensional spaces, there is a natural isomorphism $V\cong V^{**}$ which shows up a lot in linear algebra.
- The Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory is essentially the statement of duality between the intermediate fields of a Galois extension $K/F$, i.e. fields $L$ such that $F\subseteq L\subseteq K$, and subgroups of the Galois group $\Gal(K/F)$.

Recently, I came across the curious [duality between the electricity and magnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(electricity_and_magnetism)#:%7E:text=In%20physics%2C%20the%20electromagnetic%20dual,electric%20fields%20and%20magnetic%20fields.&text=Gauss%27s%20law%20for%20electric%20field,dual%20of%20the%20magnetic%20potential.) in classical physics. As I know very little about it, this duality seems to be very mysterious to me as I am missing a good explanation for why this should be true.

I am looking for a conceptual, **mathematical** explanation for:

1. In *what sense* this duality is true: is there a way to define a map from the "space of all electric fields" to the "space of all magnetic fields" which reverses the direction of arrows, whatever that means? If not, in what sense precisely is this duality a special case of duality in mathematics in general?
2. *Why* this duality holds. The Wikipedia article mentions that in special relativity, the Lorentz transformation makes electric fields into magnetic fields. However I do not understand this, as I thought the Lorentz transformations are just coordinate changes for different choices of reference frames, and I don't really get how this is related to the duality in question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you already know this, but I think it's worth saying: special relativity reveals that electric and magnetic fields are unified into a single electromagnetic field $F$, which is a differential $2$-form in four-dimensional spacetime (and thus has $4(4-1)/2=6$ independent components, $3$ of which form the electric field and the other $3$ form the magnetic field). Electric-magnetic duality is then realized as [Hodge duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) in this context, since the operation $F \mapsto F^*$ precisely interchanges the electric and magnetic fields.

Comment: @pregunton Thanks, I did not know that! (My knowledge of physics is unfortunately quite limited.) I will look into that further :)

Comment: @pregunton By the way, do you know any references which explain how the electromagnetic field arises as a differential $2$-form in special relativity? I'd like to learn this but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: I can't think of a reference off the top of my head, but the relevant keyword for the special relativistic treatment is "covariant formulation" of electromagnetism/electrodynamics, and it is usually explained in most undergraduate-level electromagnetism textbooks (familiarity with special relativity and index notation is a prerequisite to understand most expositions). [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor) might be useful as a starting point.

Comment: Another possibly useful page is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Differential_forms_approach) which describes the relationship between the index language and the form language. Usually the differential form viewpoint is not emphasized (or even mentioned) in an elementary treatment, but e.g. [this reference](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/thomas.mieling/pdf/EM_Duality.pdf) talks about the concept of duality in more detail under this viewpoint.

Comment: @pregunton Nice, thanks!